# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility - Cannot add Account Owner to Project Collection Service Account Group

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm attempting to use the tool for a TFS 2012 Migration to VS Team Services.  Validation is showing that I need permissions for my logged in User to be under the Project Collection Service Account Group.  When I try to manually add my User as a "Member Of" through the website, I get a "You do not have permissions to perform this action"

My user is the Account Owner and a member of Team Foundation Service Administrator and Project Collection Service Administrator groups.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS has recently changed this to disallow users directly changing members of Service Account. There is however, a workaround that you can use.

1. Create a new (custom) VSO Group
2. Under '**Members**', add your user.
3. Under '**Member of**', add **[DefaultCollection]Project Collection Service Accounts**
4. Go back to OVSMU and re-validate the migration that you were creating.

Comment: Thank you!  This let me pass the Validation test and migrate my projects using the tool!

marked as answer

Comment: Also, I think I was a little confused because Microsoft's documentation showed to add the User directly under the Project Collection Service Account group.  The interface looked a little outdated, so I didn't think I was in the right place, but I just wanted to point out how I got to posting this question

Microsoft
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs

Comment: Glad to know it worked. And yes, the VSO interface has changed since those instructions were written.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working without creating the group as described in the other answer.

1. From the control panel, click on the link labelled 'Manage collection security and group membership'.
2. Search for and select the user that you are going to perform the migration with in the box with the label 'Filter users and groups'.
3. Swap to the Member of tab.
4. Click the Add... button.
5. Enter the search term 'project collection service accounts' in the box labelled User or group.
6. Search for and select the group using the term '[defaultcollection]\project collection service accounts'.
7. Hit the Save changes button.