# Visual Studio Online - TFS - OpsHub - 'Users' tab missing

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops, opshub

According to this resource:

http://www.opshub.com/ohrel/Resources/TFS/permissions.php?page=serviceaccount

I should see a "Users" tab in the Security tab in the Admin section of my Visual Studio online account.

I do not..

This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnN6s.jpg

I can search for the user I am trying to grant access to, but do not have permission (even as the account owner) to add the user to the "Project Collection Service Accounts" group.

The error message I receive is: "You do not have the required permissions to perform this action."

Has anyone seen this scenario before?

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Rabbie.

Comment: Hi, Please refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899487/opshub-visual-studio-online-migration-utility-cannot-add-account-owner-to-proj for the solution

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems to have worked!